# Add date points between separate dates in a dataframe and create blanks (NA) in the other columns were those newly rows were created in r

Tags: r, na, as.date

This is how my data looks like:

```
> dput(head(h01_NDVI_specveg_data_spectra,6))
structure(list(ID = c("h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01"
), collection_date = structure(c(15076, 15092, 15125, 15139, 
15159, 15170), class = "Date"), NDVI = c(0.581769436997319, 0.539445628997868, 
0.338541666666667, 0.302713987473904, 0.305882352941176, 0.269439421338155
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have separate dates without order as you can see in the example (ex.: 2011-04-12; 2011-04-28; 2011-05-31...). What I want is to insert the missing dates between the dates that I have. On top of that, consequently, I want to create new rows for the other columns, where for NDVI those rows would be `NA`.

Check this example of the desired output:

| ID | collection_date | NDVI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h01 | **2011-04-12** | 0.5817694 |
| h01 | 2011-04-13 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-14 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-15 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-16 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-17 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-18 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-19 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-20 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-21 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-22 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-23 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-24 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-25 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-26 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-27 | NA |
| h01 | **2011-04-28** | 0.5394456 |
| h01 | 2011-04-29 | NA |
| h01 | 2011-04-30 | NA |
| ... | .......... | .. |

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about yur ID variable? How should it be used (i.e. why is everywhere the same in your expected output??)

Comment: to facilitate I separated the ID variable which makes it always the same. Ideally, I would like to maintain, "h01".

Comment: And why is the value for 2011-04-28 NA when it **has a value** in the example data?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. Sorry if it should be obvious?! However, does the answer I posted solve your problem?

Comment: Each original date (see in bold), has a value. I forgot to mention that, sorry. basically, I went to the field on random days (see in bold), and data was collected.

Comment: I still do not understand why the NDVI value for "2011-04-28" is NA  in the expected output. Also: Where should the output from the answer I posted below differ from the output you need to get?

Comment: my mistake dario, I'm sorry, see the edit on the question. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01"),
                      collection_date = structure(c(15076, 15092, 15125, 15139, 
                                 15159, 15170), class = "Date"),
                      NDVI = c(0.581769436997319, 0.539445628997868, 0.338541666666667, 0.302713987473904, 0.305882352941176, 0.269439421338155)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

We create a data.frame containing *all* dates and `tidyr::left_join` it with the existing (incomplete) data. The NA are created automatically.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(collection_date = seq.Date(min(df1$collection_date), max(df1$collection_date), "days")) %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  arrange(collection_date) %>% 
  select(ID, collection_date, everything())
```

Returns:

> ```
>      ID collection_date      NDVI
> 1   h01      2011-04-12 0.5817694
> 2  <NA>      2011-04-13        NA
> 3  <NA>      2011-04-14        NA
> 4  <NA>      2011-04-15        NA
> 5  <NA>      2011-04-16        NA
> 6  <NA>      2011-04-17        NA
> 7  <NA>      2011-04-18        NA
> 8  <NA>      2011-04-19        NA
> 9  <NA>      2011-04-20        NA
> 10 <NA>      2011-04-21        NA
> 11 <NA>      2011-04-22        NA
> 12 <NA>      2011-04-23        NA
> 13 <NA>      2011-04-24        NA
> 14 <NA>      2011-04-25        NA
> 15 <NA>      2011-04-26        NA
> 16 <NA>      2011-04-27        NA
> 17  h01      2011-04-28 0.5394456
> 18 <NA>      2011-04-29        NA
> 19 <NA>      2011-04-30        NA
> 20 <NA>      2011-05-01        NA
> 21 <NA>      2011-05-02        NA
> 22 <NA>      2011-05-03        NA
> 23 <NA>      2011-05-04        NA
> 24 <NA>      2011-05-05        NA
> 25 <NA>      2011-05-06        NA
> 26 <NA>      2011-05-07        NA
> 27 <NA>      2011-05-08        NA
> 28 <NA>      2011-05-09        NA
> 29 <NA>      2011-05-10        NA
> 30 <NA>      2011-05-11        NA
> 31 <NA>      2011-05-12        NA
> 32 <NA>      2011-05-13        NA
> 33 <NA>      2011-05-14        NA
> 34 <NA>      2011-05-15        NA
> 35 <NA>      2011-05-16        NA
> 36 <NA>      2011-05-17        NA
> 37 <NA>      2011-05-18        NA
> 38 <NA>      2011-05-19        NA
> 39 <NA>      2011-05-20        NA
> 40 <NA>      2011-05-21        NA
> 41 <NA>      2011-05-22        NA
> 42 <NA>      2011-05-23        NA
> 43 <NA>      2011-05-24        NA
> 44 <NA>      2011-05-25        NA
> 45 <NA>      2011-05-26        NA
> 46 <NA>      2011-05-27        NA
> 47 <NA>      2011-05-28        NA
> 48 <NA>      2011-05-29        NA
> 49 <NA>      2011-05-30        NA
> 50  h01      2011-05-31 0.3385417
> 51 <NA>      2011-06-01        NA
> 52 <NA>      2011-06-02        NA
> 53 <NA>      2011-06-03        NA
> 54 <NA>      2011-06-04        NA
> 55 <NA>      2011-06-05        NA
> 56 <NA>      2011-06-06        NA
> 57 <NA>      2011-06-07        NA
> 58 <NA>      2011-06-08        NA
> 59 <NA>      2011-06-09        NA
> 60 <NA>      2011-06-10        NA
> 61 <NA>      2011-06-11        NA
> 62 <NA>      2011-06-12        NA
> 63 <NA>      2011-06-13        NA
> 64  h01      2011-06-14 0.3027140
> 65 <NA>      2011-06-15        NA
> 66 <NA>      2011-06-16        NA
> 67 <NA>      2011-06-17        NA
> 68 <NA>      2011-06-18        NA
> 69 <NA>      2011-06-19        NA
> 70 <NA>      2011-06-20        NA
> 71 <NA>      2011-06-21        NA
> 72 <NA>      2011-06-22        NA
> 73 <NA>      2011-06-23        NA
> 74 <NA>      2011-06-24        NA
> 75 <NA>      2011-06-25        NA
> 76 <NA>      2011-06-26        NA
> 77 <NA>      2011-06-27        NA
> 78 <NA>      2011-06-28        NA
> 79 <NA>      2011-06-29        NA
> 80 <NA>      2011-06-30        NA
> 81 <NA>      2011-07-01        NA
> 82 <NA>      2011-07-02        NA
> 83 <NA>      2011-07-03        NA
> 84  h01      2011-07-04 0.3058824
> 85 <NA>      2011-07-05        NA
> 86 <NA>      2011-07-06        NA
> 87 <NA>      2011-07-07        NA
> 88 <NA>      2011-07-08        NA
> 89 <NA>      2011-07-09        NA
> 90 <NA>      2011-07-10        NA
> 91 <NA>      2011-07-11        NA
> 92 <NA>      2011-07-12        NA
> 93 <NA>      2011-07-13        NA
> 94 <NA>      2011-07-14        NA
> 95  h01      2011-07-15 0.2694394
> ```

## Edit:

In order to have ID = "h01" everywhere we just add it to the constructed data.frame. I.e.:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(collection_date = seq.Date(min(df1$collection_date), max(df1$collection_date), "days"),
           ID = "h01") %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  arrange(collection_date) %>% 
  select(ID, collection_date, everything())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df = structure(list(ID = c("h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01", "h01"
), collection_date = structure(c(15076, 15092, 15125, 15139, 
 15159, 15170), class = "Date"), NDVI = c(0.581769436997319, 0.539445628997868, 
 0.338541666666667, 0.302713987473904, 0.305882352941176, 0.269439421338155
 )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df2 = tibble(
  ID = "h01",
  collection_date = seq(ymd("2011-04-10"), ymd("2011-07-16"), 1)
) %>% left_join(df, by = c("ID", "collection_date"))

df2 %>% head(10)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 98 x 3
   ID    collection_date   NDVI
   <chr> <date>           <dbl>
 1 h01   2011-04-10      NA    
 2 h01   2011-04-11      NA    
 3 h01   2011-04-12       0.582
 4 h01   2011-04-13      NA    
 5 h01   2011-04-14      NA    
 6 h01   2011-04-15      NA    
 7 h01   2011-04-16      NA    
 8 h01   2011-04-17      NA    
 9 h01   2011-04-18      NA    
10 h01   2011-04-19      NA    
# ... with 88 more rows
```

output `df2 %>% tail(10)`

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   ID    collection_date   NDVI
   <chr> <date>           <dbl>
 1 h01   2011-07-07      NA    
 2 h01   2011-07-08      NA    
 3 h01   2011-07-09      NA    
 4 h01   2011-07-10      NA    
 5 h01   2011-07-11      NA    
 6 h01   2011-07-12      NA    
 7 h01   2011-07-13      NA    
 8 h01   2011-07-14      NA    
 9 h01   2011-07-15       0.269
10 h01   2011-07-16      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `tidyr::complete` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(collection_date = seq(min(collection_date), 
                 max(collection_date), by = 'days')) %>%
  ungroup

#   ID    collection_date   NDVI
#   <chr> <date>           <dbl>
# 1 h01   2011-04-12       0.582
# 2 h01   2011-04-13      NA    
# 3 h01   2011-04-14      NA    
# 4 h01   2011-04-15      NA    
# 5 h01   2011-04-16      NA    
# 6 h01   2011-04-17      NA    
# 7 h01   2011-04-18      NA    
# 8 h01   2011-04-19      NA    
# 9 h01   2011-04-20      NA    
#10 h01   2011-04-21      NA    
#11 h01   2011-04-22      NA    
#12 h01   2011-04-23      NA    
#13 h01   2011-04-24      NA    
#14 h01   2011-04-25      NA    
#15 h01   2011-04-26      NA    
#16 h01   2011-04-27      NA    
#17 h01   2011-04-28       0.539
#18 h01   2011-04-29      NA    
#19 h01   2011-04-30      NA    
#20 h01   2011-05-01      NA  
#...
#...
```

The benefit of this approach would be that it would create missing dates based on `min` and `max` for each `ID`.